# How can I redirect the same message to both stdoud and stderr (without temporary file)

Tags: shell, ksh, tee

It is easy to redirect stdout or stderr to the same output (file or one of the 2 std output) with a `1>&1`,`>&2` and/or `>file`  but is there a way to send the same output to both the std output in KSH (like `| tee File` but with `&2` as file) ?

Comment: More appropriate on http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Didn't get your question. What is problem in `command 2>&1`?

Comment: Or the combined `&> file`?

Comment: `2>&1` only redirect stdout to stdout but you loose stdout in this case. I try to have the stream to stdout AND on stderr at the same time (duplicate the output, one on each channel) but without using temporary obejct (variable or file)

Comment: @Etan Reisner: it's just the opposite of `&>` where all the stream goes to 1 stream (and it doesn not work on KSH like in BASH)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/ksh

function mytee { 
        while read -r x ; do
                print "${x}"
                print "${x}" >&2
        done
}

echo "TestMyTee
second line
and a * character" | mytee

# Really stdout and stderr?
echo "TestMyTee
second line
and a * character" | mytee 1>mystdout 2>mystderr
```

Edited: replaced [read] and [echo] by [read -r] and [print]

Comment: ok, quite simple batch, good idea. Just adapt the read to allow `\\` with a -r and maybe use a printf instead of echo to avoid interpretation by shell

Answer (score 0):

Response on Unix & Linux

[Post: How can I redirect the same message to both stdoud and stderr (without temporary object)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/167104/how-can-i-redirect-the-same-message-to-both-stdoud-and-stderr-without-temporary)

by Stéphane Chazelas

```
{ your-code } | perl -pe 'print STDERR'
```